# Cython/Python: large dataset memory issue and set operations speed-up

Tags: python, transactions, cython

I have a file which contains lots of transactions/rows. Each transaction/row contains a different number of unique items/values. The items/values of each transaction are separated by spaces. So a transaction, i.e. each line of the file, has the following form:

```
a b c d e
b c d
. . .
```

where items a, b, ..., e can be anything, from strings to numbers. 
For simplicity, let's suppose that items are just letters.

I want to read this file, keep it in memory, and use set operations on each transaction. 
Right now, I am reading the file and I am creating a list of sets. 
I convert each transaction to a set, because I would like to use the issubset() function, and generally the set operations. The problem is that if the file is too large, then I get a MemoryError.

I used Cython to declare a C-struct, in order to decrease memory usage. In this struct I keep the number of lines and the dataset in a char ** . I managed to solve the memory issue, but then I had problem with the set operations. Specifically, I implemented*** some functions that work in the same way with strings as the corresponding set operations work with sets. However, this gave a critical time overhead.

So my question consists of two parts:
a) Is there another way to decrease the memory required to store the dataset, while maintaining the sets functionality?
b) Otherwise, if I am on the right track with the C-struct, is there a way to speed-up set operations with strings in Cython?***

-- EDIT --

***I have implemented the functions in C and have them in a header file. Then I use

```
cdef extern from "header_name.h":
    ...
```

Comment: Do you *have* to store all the sets in memory at the same time? Can't you work on line-by-line, set-by-set basis (and store the result in the list)?

Comment: This would work well if only one scan to the database was enough.
But this is not always the case. That depends on the algorithm I am using. If I read the file each time, wouldn't that give a large time overhead?

Comment: I would say that if you are forced to use C to avoid memory issues you might want also use C to avoid performance problems. Would it be bad idea to implement C-module to do the hard calculation and use that as with "Popen" or as external module? What kind of output are you expecting ? Why do you strictly want to use python for the processing ?

Comment: And just to add, if your problem is really really large, and you want it to be really really fast, and the problem is really easy to parallelize, you might want to take look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyopencl

Comment: @susundberg See the EDIT part. Isn't what I do equivalent to what you describe? I have the functions in a .h file, I cdef them and then just use them in my .pyd file. The output is a modified version of the dataset. It is produced by using set operations on some transactions. I don't want to use Python for the heavy processing. Moving completely to C would be really painful. How can I replace the functionality of dictionaries for example? Problem is the C functions give a large overhead. I can post code of the functions I' ve implemented, in order to simulate set operations on C strings.

Comment: Well, a dictionary / set can't grow indefinitely without issues. I think if yours is more than about 10K elements, it's going to be painful already, memory-wise.

Comment: @Ashalynd I don't have so large sets. Problem is not the size of each set, but the number of transactions/rows, leading to a list that contains many sets. I don't have problem for files with less than 200K rows. But real datasets might contain up to 1KK transactions. I managed to load such large datasets with the C-struct implementation. But I tested the set operations with an 8K-rows dataset and I can tell that for larger datasets that require more operations, it would take like 1 year to have an output.

Comment: If so, then rewriting it in C would still take less time :-}

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve, can you explain that? I mean the purpose of your program.

Comment: @Ashalynd Why do you think rewriting in C would solve the problem?
I mean, the computationally expensive parts are writen in pure C and are (c)imported. The purpose of the program is to read the dataset and then according to an algorithm, modify it by removing certain items. (The item removal is not done randomly!) This requires multiple scans of the dataset, thus if in memory scans would be much faster.

Comment: @user3674296 i also think that you might want to open up little more what you are really trying to do and how. Debugging performance/memory problems without knowing what you do is bit hard.

And Writing the 'hard core calculation' function in C might not help, if its just using 5% of the calculation time or if the most of the calculation time is used in overhed calling C-functions.

You might also want to see profiling tools (see for example: https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) and avoid common pitfalls (https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)

Comment: @susundberg I am trying to conceal frequent patterns that exist in the dataset, by carefully removing items based on some algorithms. That's why I want to avoid rewriting the whole thing in C. Because I would have to re-write 8 algorithms. I' ve already tried profiling and used runsnake as well. My guess is that the problem is the cost of the operations. For example, my 1st implementation has a loop that applies issubset on each transaction and takes 0.007 secs. In my C-struct implementation the same loop takes 0.51 secs. But, yeah... I can't tell if it's the function or the call overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps use reversed approach?

Namely, instead of keeping a list of sets, keep a dictionary of sets. In that dictionary, the key would be an entry, and the values would be the rows where this entry appears.

E.g. if you have this:

```
row 1:  a b c d e
row 2:  a b 33 2
```

after two rows your dictionary would look like this:

```
a -> set(1,2)
b -> set(1,2)
c -> set(1)
d -> set(1)
e -> set(1)
33 -> set(2)
2 -> set(2)
```

after you go through all the rows, every entry of the dictionary would contain the numbers of all rows where it appears. (You can actually use bitset i/o set to save some space). Then you can use this structure to see which of the rows intersect.

Comment: This looks promising. I will implement it in the next days, and I' ll be more than happy to accept this as an answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: It might be still nasty to have a list or a set with 8K values (imagine that a certain entry is present in all the rows). In that case, perhaps you'd need some optimization, e.g. turning a number or consecutive values into a range (so you'll get a kind of range tree instead of a simple set). But I'm almost sure there must be code for that already.